# Excel for Mac - Macro crashing Excel - Works on Windows

Tags: excel, vba, macos

For our work-planning we created an excel document with integrated macro, so the document can be exported in a specific format for importing it in another program. The document was created on a windows pc with the latest version of Excel. The macro works perfectly on Windows. At home I use my Mac. I can edit without any problems the document, but when I run the macro, my Excel always crashes... Anyone an idea what's the problem with the Mac-version?

I posted the macro and the error-report.

Thanks!
Tim

---

**This is the macro**:

```
Sub Export()

Dim teller As Integer
Dim filename As String
Dim werkblad As Worksheet

'Nieuw werkblad "GALOP" aanmaken
With ThisWorkbook
    Set werkblad = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    werkblad.Name = "GALOP"
End With

'Kopieer headers van "GALOPvar" naar "GALOP"
Sheets("GALOPvar").Range("A1:O1").Copy
Sheets("GALOP").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Persoon per persoon aanmaken in "GALOPvar" en toevoegen aan "GALOP"
'voor PZ Maldegem: beginnen bij lijn 4, verwerken t.e.m. lijn 46 (enkel de even lijnen nemen)
For teller = 2 To 45
    Sheets("GALOPvar").Cells(1, 19).Value = teller
    If Sheets("GALOPvar").Cells(2, 1).Value <> 0 Then
        Sheets("GALOPvar").Range("A2:O63").Copy
        Sheets("GALOP").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End If
    'enkel de even lijnen nemen, dus eentje bijtellen om de oneven lijnen over te slaan
Next teller

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'foutcodes verwijderen, dagdiensten toevoegen na TIR
Call ClearGALOP


'Tabblad "GALOP" verplaatsen naar nieuw werkblad en opslaan
Sheets("GALOP").Move

filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'tabbladen terug inladen voor dropdownlijstje
Application.Calculate

'origineel tabblad "GALOPvar" terug actief zetten
Sheets("GALOPvar").Activate

End Sub

'tabblad "GALOP" bottom-up overlopen en:
'lijnen waar kolom D ("characterization") een error geeft, eruit gooien
'na lijnen waar kolom C ("code") TIR is, dagdienst toevoegen (beperkte uren)
Sub ClearGALOP()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long

    With Sheets("GALOP")
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
            'tir aanvullen met dagdienst
            If UCase(.Cells(Lrow, "C").Value) = "W" Then
                'kopieer lijn TIR
                .Cells(Lrow, "C").EntireRow.Offset(1).Insert
                .Cells(Lrow, "C").EntireRow.Copy .Cells(Lrow, "C").EntireRow.Offset(1)
                .Cells(Lrow, "C").EntireRow.Offset(1).Insert
                .Cells(Lrow, "C").EntireRow.Copy .Cells(Lrow, "C").EntireRow.Offset(1)
                'wijzig nieuwe TIR in D
                .Cells(Lrow + 1, "C").Value = "MAT"
                .Cells(Lrow + 2, "C").Value = "TIR"
                'wijzig startuur naar 13:00 (=780)
                .Cells(Lrow + 1, "E").Value = 780
                .Cells(Lrow + 2, "E").Value = 900
                'wijzig einduur naar 15:36 (=936)
                .Cells(Lrow + 1, "F").Value = 900
                .Cells(Lrow + 2, "F").Value = 1020
                'geen pauze
                .Cells(Lrow + 1, "G").Value = 0
                .Cells(Lrow + 1, "H").Value = 0
                .Cells(Lrow + 2, "G").Value = 0
                .Cells(Lrow + 2, "H").Value = 0
                'wijzig activitykey naar 542401000000184
                .Cells(Lrow + 1, "I").Value = 543801000000193#
                .Cells(Lrow + 2, "I").Value = 543801000000194#
                'geen maaltijdvergoeding
                .Cells(Lrow + 1, "M").Value = 4
                .Cells(Lrow + 2, "M").Value = 4
            End If

            'errors eruit
            With .Cells(Lrow, "D")
                If IsError(.Value) Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End With

        Next Lrow
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**This is the error-report (part 1)**:

> Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0
>
> Error Signature: Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ExceptionEnumString: 1
>   Exception Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS (0x0000000000000000) Date/Time:
>   2018-01-07 15:56:10 +0000 Application Name: Microsoft Excel
>   Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Excel Application Signature: XCEL
>   Application Bitness: x64 Application Version: 15.41.0.17120500 Crashed
>   Module Name: Microsoft Excel Crashed Module Version: 15.41.0.171205
>   Crashed Module Offset: 0x0000000000c7c68f Blame Module Name: Microsoft
>   Excel Blame Module Version: 15.41.0.171205 UnsymbolicatedChecksum:
>   AE94F3BCE48118A18C421BD384B8B4A8 Blame Module Offset:
>   0x0000000000c7c68f StackHash: d6e963f03ad36333-dm_1_main Application
>   LCID: 1043 Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0413 Build Type: SHIP Crashed
>   thread Stack Pointer: 0x_00007ffee3605c90 Audience: Production
>   AudienceGroup: Production AudienceChannel: CC Crashed thread: 0

Comment: Try by replacing the enum values by their numeric values; i.e. replace `xlPasteValues` with `-4163`, `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` with `12` and  `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` with `FileFormat:=51` . Possible that Mac doesn't know the descriptive enum.   P.S: All enum values here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpastetype-enumeration-excel . P.P.S: Just in case this is not sufficient, you might also need to replace `xlUp`with `-4162` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xldirection-enumeration-excel

Comment: More info: Apparently, Mac VBA does not support the Enum type: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.mac.office.word/cX9HSNmlLNQ
So, yeah, this makes it even more probably the xl-Enums are the cause of the error. replace them with their integer equivalent as in my comment above.

Comment: Hey @LocEngineer, thanks already for the comment. I changed the code, but when I try the step-by-step compiler, I get multiple errors at the part after:
`Sheets("GALOP").Move`

Strange that VBA doesn't work the same way in Windows/Mac.

Comment: Hi Tim, please post details of the errors you receive as well as the exact line where the respective error occurs. There are differences between Win/Mac VBA. Especiall y `FileFilter`obviously does not work with `GetSaveAsFileName ` on Mac. See here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac016.htm

Comment: Ok, I tried deleting everything beneath the `Sheets("GALOP").Move`. VBA didn't find any errors and I could run the whole thing from within VBA. The moment I put it on a button, the same thing happens again... Excel crashes...

I'm beginning to think it's a bug in Excel.

Comment: Or the button! Is it a Foms control button or an ActiveX control? Forms might work, ActiveX certainly doesn't on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem. Can you try eliminating this line?

> 'origineel tabblad "GALOPvar" terug actief zetten
>
> Sheets("GALOPvar").Activate

I've had Excel on MacOs crashing on `activate`.

Another thing you can try is insert a DoEvents before the `activate`